# How to divide the difference in two times in python to find the difference as a percentage of the year?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to find the difference between two times and see what it is as a percentage of the year. I am subtracting a future date from today's date. For example, if the future date is two days from now, I would subtract the two dates and compute that the difference is 2. Then I would like to divide it by 365 and obtain the percentage 0.5%

So far, I managed to find the difference between two dates, however when I try to divide I just get a time as the output. Here is my code below and the outputs:

```
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 

#Time to Expiration:
expTime = input("What is the date of expiry (yyyy-mm-dd)?: ")
expTime = datetime.strptime(expTime, "%Y-%m-%d")
today = datetime.today()
duration = expTime - today
duration_in_s = duration.total_seconds()
daysRemaining = duration.days
daysRemaining = divmod(duration_in_s, 86400)[0]
daysRemaining = (expTime - today)
#Days remaining as a percentage of the year
t = daysRemaining/365.0
print(t)
```

Output:

```
What is the date of expiry (yyyy-mm-dd)?:  2021-09-21

print(t)
6:21:03.861188

print(daysRemaining)
96 days, 14:08:29.333438
```

Also, if I would just like days remaining, how would I get rid of the timestamp?

Thank you!

ANSWER:

I modified my code based on the comments and answers given to:

```
#Time to Expiration:
expTime = input("What is the date of expiry (yyyy-mm-dd)?: ")
expTime = datetime.strptime(expTime, "%Y-%m-%d")
today = datetime.today()
daysRemaining = (expTime - today)
print("There are", daysRemaining,"days until expiration.")
#Days remaining as a percentage of the year
daysRemaining = round(((daysRemaining.total_seconds()/86400/365.24)*100),3)
print("This is", daysRemaining, "% of the year.")
```

Comment: `((duration.total_seconds()/86400)/365.24)*100`?

Comment: You could try `t = daysRemaining.days/365.0`?

Comment: Both of these worked :) thank you guys!!!!

Comment: Why did you have 3 different ways of calculating `daysRemaining`?  Any but the last would have worked fine I think.

Comment: Are you OK with the algorithm not accounting for leap years?

Comment: @MarkRansom How would I account for leap year?

Comment: Instead of using a constant 365 days, use the difference between two days that are exactly a year apart.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the best way but you can make something like this :

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()
future = datetime.date(2021,6,20)
diff = future - today
diff = diff.days
percentage = diff/365
```

Comment: oups yes you rigth is my bad